# unable to install jet plugin on eclipse JUNO

Tags: eclipse-juno, eclipse-emf, eclipse-jet

hello guys i tried to download Jet as an EMF Component but it doesn't work , so i tried to download  an  [archived update](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/modeling/m2t/jet/downloads/drops/1.1.0/R201006081558/m2t-jet-Update-1.1.0.zip)

i get the following error :

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.modeling, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jet,1.1.1.v201101311015.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 5bb513bb6cc5dcc936ddb22aebcd0af4 and found 9e831f7e6d7532b3afd6bc76c48885de.

Comment: I have the same problem currently. There is already a bug for this issue. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358574 I will search for a solution as well..

Answer (score 0):

After some trying, I found a way that works, at least for me.

As noted in the [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358574), the latest version of [Eclipse JET](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/downloads/?project=jet) requires UML2 in a version strictly below 4.0.0. The Version that comes with Juno is 4.0.1., so Eclipse will refuse to install. Similarly, UML2 3.1.2 (the latest version available below 4.0.0) requires EMF in a version below 2.7, while Juno's version is 2.8, so this won't install either.

However, note that UML2, version 3.1.2, is also available in editions other than the update site. You can download the [mdt-uml2-SDK-3.1.2.zip](http://archive.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/downloads/drops/3.1.2/R201101311648/), unzip the archive, and simply merge the `features` and `plugins` folders into you Eclipse installation, thus circumventing Eclipse being picky about the version numbers.

Step by step:

1. install Eclipse Juno, install other features (EMF, SVN, etc.), exit Eclipse
2. (optionally, create a backup, in case something goes wrong)
3. get [mdt-uml2-SDK-3.1.2.zip](http://archive.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/downloads/drops/3.1.2/R201101311648/), and merge its `features` and `plugins` into your Eclipse installation
4. get the [JET 1.1.1 Update Site](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/downloads/?project=jet), and install JET via Eclipse's install mechanisms

As far as I've tested, everything seems to work.